# MS Access 2003/2007 - Subform as control panel, closing parent form with global like reference?

Tags: ms-access, forms, vba, subform

I am sorry if the title is wrong, but I think that is what I mean to ask.

So I have a subform created that I would like to use, sort of like a control panel, that allows user to select a range of different forms. So the same subform ends up in a lot of different parent forms. I would like to use simple

```
docmd.close acform
```

but i am looking for a way to reference the parent form like "active form" or something like that so I can close whatever form is open before opening the intended form. that way i can use the same sub form (control panel) in a lot of forms and it works globally??

thanks
justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within the subform you can get the name of its parent form with:

```
Me.Parent.Name
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Beware, if you ever open the subform's form on its own (not as a subform of a parent form), Me.Parent will give you an Invalid Reference error.  You can trap that error if needed with code like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028760/possible-to-set-filter-on-subform-from-parent-form-before-subform-data-loads/3029381#3029381

Comment: Also I'm unsure whether you can have a subform close its parent, then open a different form.  You might have better luck opening the new form, then closing the previous parent.

Comment: seems to be working just fine. I am simply using this ONLY as a control panel (navigation menu) for all available forms within a certain context. There is no need to have the form open on its own. Yes it seems to work closing the parent form, then opening the new one. I already changed and tested that method, and it is working fine so??? thanks Hans!!

Comment: If you use Me.Parent, it returns a form object, and can be used like any form reference. Doesn't help your problem, but I thought it was useful for that to be explicitly mentioned.